# Redirect console output for just one method

Tags: c#, console, output

I have here a bunch of unit tests. One of them expects the code to do nothing because the arguments parsing should not work.

Unfortunately, the arguments parsing library I'm using forces `Console.Write()` in this case, and now my unit tests output is full of the library's messages, which makes it hard to read.

Is there a way to redirect the standard console output to nothing (or a temp file or whatever) before calling this method, and then redirecting it back to the standard output once it's finished ?

Thanks!

## Update

Actually it's the error output that needs to be redirected...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can temporary replace output stream with a custom one. It can be done with [Console.SetOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) method. More or less (adapting to your actual code, see also comments):

```
// We're not interested in its output, a NULL fake one may also work (better)
Console.SetOut(new StringWriter());

// Your code here...

// Now you have to restore default output stream
var standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
```

**UPDATE**: according to your update (redirect of standard *error* stream) you simply need to replace `*Out` with `*Error`:

```
Console.SetError(new StringWriter());

// Your code here...

var standardError = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardError());
standardError.AutoFlush = true;
Console.SetError(standardError);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can create a `TextWriter` that does nothing:

```
public sealed class NulTextWriter: TextWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can set and restore the console output like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enabled");

var saved = Console.Out;
Console.SetOut(new NulTextWriter());
Console.WriteLine("This should not appear");

Console.SetOut(saved);
Console.WriteLine("Restored");
```

You can use the same approach for the console's error output:

```
Console.Error.WriteLine("Enabled");

var saved = Console.Error;
Console.SetError(new NulTextWriter());
Console.Error.WriteLine("This should not appear");

Console.SetError(saved);
Console.Error.WriteLine("Restored");
```

Comment: this one is perfect, specially for third party applications throwing messages in our build server during tests..

Comment: Nice reusing of the existing writer and output stream! For temporary output redirection, this seems more lightweight than opening another output stream.